# How to make Django redirect after validating an uploaded file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, file-upload

Instead, the page just reloads. When I check my server logs nothing is happening. This tells me that either the page isn't uploading or my `views.py` has a problem but I'm not sure what that could be.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'transcribeSubmit' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="transcribe-file" class="transcribe-file-label">
    <input id="transcribe-file" name="audio-video" type="file" accept="audio/*, video/*" hidden>
    <button class="upload" id="transcribe-submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("transcribe-file").addEventListener("change", function(event){
    document.getElementById("transcribe-submit").click();
});
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from .models import TranscribedDocument
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

# Create your views here.

@csrf_protect
def transcribeSubmit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                audio_file = form.save()
                return redirect('/t/')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            error_message = f"An error occurred: {e}"
            return JsonResponse({'error': error_message}, status=500)

    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        
    return render(request,'transcribe/transcribe.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
import mimetypes
import magic
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_file(file):
    # Validate if no file submitted (size = None)
    if file is None:
        raise ValidationError("No file submitted")
    else:

        #Check file size
        fileSize = file.size
        maxSize = 5242880  # 5MB in bytes (also: 5 * 1024 * 1024)
    
        if fileSize > maxSize:###test
            raise ValidationError("The maximum file size that can be uploaded is 10MB")
        else:

            try:
                # Check the file extension
                file_type = str(file.name).lower().split('.')[-1]

                #add more
                allowed_types = {
            'm4a': 'audio/mp4',
            'wav': ['audio/wav', 'audio/x-wav'],
            'mp3': 'audio/mpeg',
            'mpeg': 'video/mpeg',
            'mp4': 'video/mp4',
            'webm': 'video/webm',
            'mpga': 'audio/mpeg'
            }
                
                if file_type not in allowed_types.keys():
                    raise ValidationError(f"Unsupported file type. Allowed types are: {', '.join(accepted_types)}")

                

        # Create a magic object to check the file MIME type from content
                validator = magic.Magic(uncompress=True, mime=True)
        
        # Get the MIME type  based on content
                mime_type = validator.from_buffer(file.read(1000))#


        # Check if the guessed MIME type and content-based MIME type match
                if mime_type not in allowed_types[file_type]:
                    raise ValidationError(f"incorrect extension")
            
            except Exception as e:
                raise ValidationError(f"Validation error: {str(e)}")

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(validators=[validate_file])
```

I tried submitting the file using AJAX but there was no difference and the page again reloaded without any change or redirection.
Additionally I checked my urls.py and there is no error.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your `urls.py` ?

Comment: @ArunT Hi. I figured out why. It's because in my HTML I gave `<input>`  tag `name="audio-video"` when it should be `file` to match my forms.py class'  attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect after validating an uploaded file in Django, you can modify your transcribeSubmit view function to return a redirect response after the file has been successfully validated and saved. Here's how you can modify your code:

from django.urls import reverse

```
def transcribeSubmit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            audio_file = form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('transcribeSuccess'))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe.html', {'form': form})

def transcribeSuccess(request):
    return HttpResponse('File uploaded successfully!')
```

In this modified code, after the file has been successfully validated and saved, the transcribeSubmit view function returns a redirect response to the transcribeSuccess view function. The transcribeSuccess view function simply returns an HTTP response indicating that the file was uploaded successfully.

You will also need to add a URL pattern for the transcribeSuccess view function in your urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('transcribe/', views.transcribeSubmit, name='transcribeSubmit'),
    path('transcribe/success/', views.transcribeSuccess, name='transcribeSuccess'),
]
```

This URL pattern maps the /transcribe/success/ URL to the transcribeSuccess view function.